# How to provide reflecting water animation on Image

Tags: android, animation, reflection, android-animation, bitmapimage

My requirement to create reflecting water animation on image.
like following link.
[water reflection](http://www162.lunapic.com/editor/?action=reflection.)

I tried using ripple effect but my requirement is to create animation like above link.

Kindly suggest me

Comment: Have you got Solution?

Comment: Gaurav , could you find any solution?I have same challenge too.I could create sine wave effect but can not create right frames for it.I appreciate any guide line you provide